# Birt data cube column sorting

Tags: sorting, birt, cube, columnsorting

I am trying to sort the datacube on the Aging Group column to appear in the following order 1-30, 31-60, 61-90 etc image located here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Caoj8.jpg

I initially thought I would modify the sort option for ascending but it did not work. I tried to modify the data from "string" to "float", but I have one category listed as "Not Aged" (equivalent to 0) and it triggers errors.

I have built an expression to create a custom sort on the datacube, but it does not seem to be working.

```
var pattern = /^[N]/gi;
if (dimension["Group1"]["CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION"] == 'Not Aged'){1}
else if (dimension["Group1"]["CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION"] == '1-30'){2}
else if (dimension["Group1"]["CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION"] == '31-60'){3}
else if (dimension["Group1"]["CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION"] == '61-90'){4}
else if (dimension["Group1"]["CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION"] == '91-120'){5} 
else if (dimension["Group1"]["CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION"] == '121-150'){6}
else if (dimension["Group1"]["CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION"] == '151-180'){7}
else if (dimension["Group1"]["CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION"] == '181-210'){8}
else if (dimension["Group1"]["CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION"] == '211-240'){9}
else if (dimension["Group1"]["CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION"] == '241-270'){10} 
else if (dimension["Group1"]["CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION"] == '271-300'){11}
else if (dimension["Group1"]["CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION"] == '331-365'){12}
else if (dimension["Group1"]["CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION"] == '331-365'){13}
else if (dimension["Group1"]["CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION"] == '366+'){14}   
else {99}
```

The data is still displaying as per the screen shot and since "Not Aged" is 0 I'd like for it to be listed first.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to figure it out!

On the datacube in the actual row cell -- I mapped the Not Aged to display as 0

On the datacube I then added an attribute of "age" to the Category Description. I was then able to sort on the DataCube using the following: dimension["Group1"]["CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION"]["DISCHARGE_AGE"] in the Ascending order.